# CGRect in C code

Tags: c, core-graphics

A simple google search for:

> CGRect + C

or

> CGRect in C

brings back only Apple, iPhone, and Objective-C websites.  However, I remember hearing that Core Graphics was part of C at my university.  Did I hear incorrectly, or is CGRect something that I can use in C, or even C++ as it's Object oriented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGRect is defined in Carbon, which is plain C:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
int main()
{
    CGRect r;
}
```

If you look at preprocessor output you'll notice CGRect is just a plain struct:

```
$ gcc -E test.c | grep -A 3 "struct.*CGRect"
struct CGRect {
  CGPoint origin;
  CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

Comment: More accurately, it's defined in Core Graphics, which both Carbon and Cocoa depend on.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use it in C or C++, but only on Apple platforms (Mac or iPhone). It's not a part of the standard C environment, if that's what you were asking.